# Where did Hitler go?

Tags: doom-2, doom-3-bfg-edition

I was playing Doom 2 in the Doom 3: BFG Edition on Steam over this weekend.

When I was in Level 31: Wolfenstein and Level 32: Grosse, I noticed that the portraits of Hitler and swastikas that denote the locations of secrets were missing, making the secrets much more difficult to find.

Were those removed just for the BFG Edition of Doom 2, or were those removed from the DOS version of Doom 2 in later versions?

Edit: This was purchased from the US Steam store.

Comment: There's a sentence I never thought I'd read...

Comment: @imulsion Provocative titles are an Arqade thing. :D

Comment: Best guess: They were removed so they could sell the same SKU in Germany, which has laws about when/where/why one may display Nazi symbols.

Comment: Yeah, they used to arrest people using swastikas in *anti*-Nazi/Fascist protests.

Comment: In case it's relevant, I'm in the US and bought it from the US Steam store.

Comment: @Powerlord I got it gifted from a US friend to me in Germany. The fact I can play it says all. They've been removed for everyone world wide. As a comparison, Wolfenstein itself is IP locked, you can't even play it here when you got a Gift, you have to buy it on German Steam Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has answered this yet (although @NoneOfYourBusiness's comments were a lead), there [were a number of changes to Ultimate Doom and Doom 2 in the Doom 3 BFG Edition](http://doomwiki.org/wiki/Doom_3:_BFG_Edition#Differences_with_Doom_and_Doom_2).

Among the changes were:

- All Wolfenstein SS have been search-and-replaced by zombiemen.
- The `ZWOLF*` texture with Nazi iconography (Hitler portraits, swastikas, Reichsadlers, etc.) now look like their unadorned counterparts.

The original Doom and Doom 2 sold separately on Steam and the like are unaffected by these changes.